# how update a valor in sqlite3 in my discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

i do a bot discord and i created a sql_base's named "Users.db" and i'm trying to modify the case xp but i don't have any idea how to do.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        print("hopla")
        await bot.process_commands(message)

    else:
        xp = 1
        string_test = "UPDATE USERS set xp_ecrit = " + (( (xp_ecrit) + 1 + ))" where name=" + str(message.author) + ";"

        print(string_test)
```

I put on bracket my problem, can i do something like value = xp_ecrit where name = "example"?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You can't do math and/or use integers/floats in your string concatenation. Calculate the new value before the string formatting and then concatenate the string representation of the number in the variable - something like `"UPDATE..." + str(xp_ecrit) + "WHERE..." `

Comment: oh ok, and do you know how can i recover the value, i search but i dont find how to do:

value = xp_ecrit where id = 2 (its an example) :s

Comment: Looks like you are using SQLite, if so check out their tutorials to CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete). Here's the [SQLite Python](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/) docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finished my project but if it's can be usefull for someone in this world. To update a valor in sqlite3 you have to do that:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('Users.db')

with con:
            curr = con.cursor()
            sql = ("UPDATE USERS SET variable1 = ? where variable2 = ?")
            val = (var1, var2)
            curr.execute(sql, val)
```

Have a nice day!